# How do I interpret this two variables function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've only taken math courses that have one independent variable in them (no calculus 2 yet), so I'm stumped trying to understand what's going on here:

f(y1, y2) = {3y1,  0 ≤ y2 ≤ y1 ≤ 1;     0, elsewhere}

Especially for this domain (is it even a domain?) what's going on here?

```
0 ≤ y2 ≤ y1 ≤ 1
```

What does the y2 ≤ y1 mean? Does it mean on the y1y2 plane, all points where y2 ≤ y1 takes on the function 3y1, and all points where y2 > y1 takes the 0 value? If so, would

```
0 ≤ y2 = y1 ≤ 1
```

mean that all points in the square (0,0) (1,0) (1,1) (0,1) takes on the function 3y1?

Comment: Hint: on the boundary of the domain, one has $0 = y_2$ or $y_2 = y_1$ or $y_1 = 1$. Draw a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 3x, \ 0\le y\le x\le 1 \\ 0, \ elsewhere \end{cases}.$$
Note that $y\le x$ is the region below and on the line $y=x$. Once the borders $0$ and $1$ are placed, the region is constrained to the triangle with the vertices: $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1)$.